# Game Testing with Monkeyrunner

Tags: android, unit-testing, cocos2d-iphone, andengine, monkeyrunner

Is it possible to test a game with Android Monkeyrunner tool. The Game developed using AndEngine or Cocos2D. If yes, how can we get the sprites in the test code?

With By class we can fetch the Android components(textfield, button...) on the screen but how can we fetch the sprites?

Answer (score 0):

Monkeyrunner understands only co-ordinates. To press a button you pass x,y co-ordinates.
It is not possible for it to capture the sprite alone from display.
It can capture the display buffer and write to an image file. 
Hence for testing the presence of specific sprite in the whole image you can use
imagemagick compare.exe from command line.

e.g.

1. Capture the whole image from monkeyrunner.
2. Have a reference sprite image for comparison.
3. Execute below mentioned from command line

   compare.exe -metric NCC deviceRefImg WholeImage diffimage.png

Output value(NCC) refers if the sprite exists in whole image.

Thank You.